# Big-O Notation Q

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a few True/False questions I need to answer, I don't know how to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

(a) True or false: Suppose that you develop an algorithm whose run-time is given by f(n) = 5f(n/2) + 3 for n = 2,4,8,16,32,..., and f(1) = 7. Then the run-time of your algorithm is O(n3), but it is not O(n2).

(b) True or false: f (n) = n3n satisfies the recurrence relation f (n) = 6f (n − 1) − 9f(n−2).

Comment: It's not clear what operations occur in first function of part (b). Can you please edit your question to include the math operators? For example, "n^2" rather than "n2".

Answer (score 1):

For part (a) you can apply the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)). The non recursive overhead is O(1), the 'critical' function n^{log_b(a)} is n^{\log_2(5)} = n^{2.321928}. So the algorithm runs in θ(n^{2.321928}), meaning it is **not** O(n^2). But, it is O(n^3).